# How to change from pre-production to production upgrade in TFS?

Tags: tfs

I am performing a migration upgrade from TFS 2015 to TFS 2018. I have performed the **pre-production** upgrade and everything went successful. I now wish to perform the production upgrade with a new set of DB backups but I do not see the option for the **production** upgrade in the Team Foundation Server Administration Console. How to do tell TFS to move from pre-production to production upgrade?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to unconfigure the app tier.

[image]
Ref: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/tfssetup/2017/09/25/unconfigure-team-foundation-server/